# Is there a way of specifying a default input argument for Mapstruct when using multiple source values?

Tags: java, mapstruct

So in the example below, I have 2 inputs object, being mapped to one output object.
The majority of the mappings are direct from one input, to one output, with only one coming from another object.

```
    @Mapping(source = "input.a" target = "output.a")
    @Mapping(source = "input.b" target = "output.b")
    @Mapping(source = "input.c" target = "output.c")
    @Mapping(source = "input.d" target = "output.d")
    @Mapping(source = "extra.a" target = "output.extraa")
    Output toOutputMapper(Input input, ExtraValues extra)
```

Is there a way to say "use this object as default", which saves me mapping the values and forgoing the automatic mapping Mapstruct provides?

Something like:

```
    @Mapping(source = "extra.a" target = "output.extraa")
    Output toOutputMapper(@Default Input input, ExtraValues extra)
```

Answer (score 1):

When using MapStruct 1.4 you can use mapping to current target to achieve what you are looking for.

e.g.

```
    @Mapping(source = "input" target = ".")
    @Mapping(source = "extra.a" target = "output.extraa")
    Output toOutputMapper(Input input, ExtraValues extra)
```